# geotools delete select featurelayer from map

Tags: javafx, geotools

I want to select featurelayer from map to delete it.

First i add some polygons graphically like this image:

[image]

Now i want to select any red feature using `MOUSE_MOVED` event, and after right click over one polygon and show contextMenu with delete item:

```
mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
            Point2D.Double current = transformScrToWrl(e.getX(), e.getY());
            selectLayer(current.getX(), current.getY());
});

...

MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem(LangHelper.getString("delete"));
    item1.setOnAction(event -> {
        Point2D.Double pnt = transformScrToWrl(x, y);
        deletePolygon(pnt.getX(), pnt.getY());
    });

ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(item1);

mapCanvas.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    menu.show(mapCanvas, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
    e.consume();
});

...

private void deletePolygon(double x, double y) {
    //Todo complete delete polygon

    map.removeLayer(selectedLayer.get());
    refreshMap();
}
```

I put the same SelectionLab `selectFeature()` code from geotools on `selectLayer(x, y)` with some changes. but code doesnt work like i expected.

[image]

`selectLayer` selects feature map in cyan color and not select in yellow previous inserted red polygons. Is there any code to select one of the polygon inserted graphically? Sorry for my english.

My code. `DistribTabPageController`

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTWriter;
import cu.edu.cujae.guatini.Main;
import cu.edu.cujae.guatini.dao.DistributionDAO;
import cu.edu.cujae.guatini.helper.LangHelper;
import cu.edu.cujae.guatini.model.Distribution;
import cu.edu.cujae.guatini.model.Species;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.DirectPosition2D;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.geotools.renderer.GTRenderer;
import org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer;
import org.geotools.styling.*;
import org.geotools.styling.Stroke;
import org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryDescriptor;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;
import org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DistribTabPageController {
    @FXML
    private Canvas mapCanvas;

    private MapContent map;
    private GraphicsContext gc;

    private GeometryFactory factory;

    private ObservableList<Coordinate> coordList;
    private ObservableList<Layer> pointList;
    private ObservableList<Geometry> polygonListInsert, polygonListUpdate, polygonListDelete;

    private Style stylePolygon, stylePoint;

    private String geometryAttributeName = "the_geom";

    private Species species;

    private boolean repaint = true;

    private double baseDrageX, baseDrageY, x, y;

    private static final double PAINT_HZ = 60.0;

    private WKTReader reader;
    private WKTWriter writer;

    private ObjectProperty<Layer> selectedLayer;

    /*
     * Factories that we will use to create style and filter objects
     */
    private StyleFactory sf;
    private FilterFactory2 ff;

    /*
     * Convenient constants for the type of feature geometry in the shapefile
     */
    private enum GeomType {
        POINT,
        LINE,
        POLYGON
    }

    /*
     * Some default style variables
     */
    private static final Color LINE_COLOUR = Color.BLUE, FILL_COLOUR = Color.CYAN, SELECTED_COLOUR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final float OPACITY = 1.0f, LINE_WIDTH = 1.0f, POINT_SIZE = 10.0f;

    private SimpleFeatureSource featureSource;

    private GeomType geometryType;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
        ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

        selectedLayer = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        writer = new WKTWriter();
        reader = new WKTReader();

        coordList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        pointList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        polygonListInsert = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        polygonListUpdate = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        polygonListDelete = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        stylePolygon = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.RED, Color.RED, 0.5f);
        stylePoint = SLD.createPointStyle("Circle", Color.RED, Color.RED, 0.5f, 10);

        factory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        gc = mapCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        initMap();
        drawMap(gc);
        initEvent();
        initPaintThread();
    }

    public void setDistributions(Species species) {
        this.species = species;

        ObservableList<Distribution> dist = DistributionDAO.getDistributionsBySpecies(species.getId());

        if (!dist.isEmpty()) {
            dist.forEach(distr -> {
                try {
                    Geometry geometry = reader.read(distr.getGeometry());
                    addGeometry(geometry, stylePolygon);
                    polygonListUpdate.add(geometry);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });
        }
    }

    private void convertAndInsert(double x, double y) {
        Point2D.Double pointD = transformScrToWrl(x, y);
        addPoint(pointD.getX(), pointD.getY());
    }

    private Point2D.Double transformScrToWrl(double x, double y) {
        Point2D.Double pointS = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        Point2D.Double pointD = new Point2D.Double();
        map.getViewport().getScreenToWorld().transform(pointS, pointD);
        return pointD;
    }

    private Layer addGeometry(Geometry geom, Style style) {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Location");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        builder.add(geometryAttributeName, Geometry.class);

        SimpleFeatureType type = builder.buildFeatureType();
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
        featureBuilder.add(geom);

        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

        DefaultFeatureCollection simpleFeatures = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
        simpleFeatures.add(feature);

        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(simpleFeatures, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);
        refreshMap();
        return layer;
    }

    private void addPoint(double x, double y) {
        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(x, y);
        Layer layer = addGeometry(factory.createPoint(coordinate), stylePoint);
        coordList.add(coordinate);
        pointList.add(layer);
    }

    private void addPolygon(Coordinate[] coordinates) {
        if (coordList.size() > 3) {
            Geometry polygon = factory.createPolygon(coordinates);
            addGeometry(polygon, stylePolygon);
            polygonListInsert.add(polygon);
        }
        map.layers().removeAll(pointList);
        pointList.clear();
        coordList.clear();
    }

    private void deletePolygon(double x, double y) {
        //Todo completar delete polygon

        map.removeLayer(selectedLayer.get());
        refreshMap();
    }

    private void initMap() {
        try {
            map = loadMap();
            map.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle((int) mapCanvas.getWidth(), (int) mapCanvas.getHeight()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void drawMap(GraphicsContext gc) {
        if (!repaint) {
            return;
        }
        repaint = false;
        StreamingRenderer draw = new StreamingRenderer();
        draw.setMapContent(map);
        FXGraphics2D graphics = new FXGraphics2D(gc);
        graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, (int) mapCanvas.getWidth(), (int) mapCanvas.getHeight());
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int) mapCanvas.getWidth(), (int) mapCanvas.getHeight());
        draw.paint(graphics, rectangle, map.getViewport().getBounds());
    }

    /*
     *initial for mouse event
     */
    private void initEvent() {
        /*
         * setting the original coordinate
         */

        mapCanvas.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> mapCanvas.requestFocus());

        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
            Point2D.Double current = transformScrToWrl(e.getX(), e.getY());
            selectLayer(current.getX(), current.getY());
        });

        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            baseDrageX = e.getSceneX();
            baseDrageY = e.getSceneY();
            e.consume();
        });

        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem(LangHelper.getString("delete"));
        item1.setOnAction(event -> {

            //saveImage(map, file, (int) mapCanvas.getWidth());
            Point2D.Double pnt = transformScrToWrl(x, y);
            deletePolygon(pnt.getX(), pnt.getY());

        });
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(item1);

        mapCanvas.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            //show only if selectedLayer is not null
            if (selectedLayer.get() != null){
                menu.show(mapCanvas, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            }

            e.consume();
        });

        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
            System.out.println("key released");
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL && !coordList.isEmpty()) {

                coordList.add(coordList.get(0));

                addPolygon(coordList.toArray(new Coordinate[]{}));

                refreshMap();
            }
        });

        /*
         * translate according to the mouse drag
         */
        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e -> {
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                convertAndInsert(e.getX(), e.getY());
            } else {
                double difX = e.getSceneX() - baseDrageX;
                double difY = e.getSceneY() - baseDrageY;
                baseDrageX = e.getSceneX();
                baseDrageY = e.getSceneY();
                DirectPosition2D newPos = new DirectPosition2D(difX, difY);
                DirectPosition2D result = new DirectPosition2D();
                map.getViewport().getScreenToWorld().transform(newPos, result);
                ReferencedEnvelope env = new ReferencedEnvelope(map.getViewport().getBounds());
                env.translate(env.getMinimum(0) - result.x, env.getMaximum(1) - result.y);
                doSetDisplayArea(env);
            }
            e.consume();

        });
        /*
         * double clicks to restore to original map
         */
        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, t -> {
            menu.hide();
            if (t.getClickCount() > 1) {
                doSetDisplayArea(map.getMaxBounds());
            }
            t.consume();
        });

        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                convertAndInsert(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            e.consume();
        });

        /*
         * scroll for zoom in and out
         */
        mapCanvas.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, e -> {
            ReferencedEnvelope envelope = map.getViewport().getBounds();
            double percent = -e.getDeltaY() / mapCanvas.getWidth();
            double width = envelope.getWidth();
            double height = envelope.getHeight();
            double deltaW = width * percent;
            double deltaH = height * percent;
            envelope.expandBy(deltaW, deltaH);
            doSetDisplayArea(envelope);
            e.consume();
        });
    }

    private void selectLayer(double x, double y) {

        //Todo SelectionLab code from geotools.org doesnt work

        System.out.println("Mouse moved at: " + x + " : " + y);

        /*
         * Construct a 5x5 pixel rectangle centred on the mouse click position
         */
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(((int) x - 2), ((int) x - 2), 5, 5);

        /*
         * Transform the screen rectangle into bounding box in the coordinate
         * reference system of our map context. Note: we are using a naive method
         * here but GeoTools also offers other, more accurate methods.
         */
        AffineTransform screenToWorld = map.getViewport().getScreenToWorld();
        Rectangle2D worldRect = screenToWorld.createTransformedShape(screenRect).getBounds2D();
        ReferencedEnvelope bbox =
                new ReferencedEnvelope(
                        worldRect, map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());

        /*
         * Create a Filter to select features that intersect with
         * the bounding box
         */
        Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property(geometryAttributeName), ff.literal(bbox));

        /*
         * Use the filter to identify the selected features
         */
        try {
            SimpleFeatureCollection selectedFeatures = featureSource.getFeatures(filter);

            Set<FeatureId> IDs = new HashSet<>();
            try (SimpleFeatureIterator iter = selectedFeatures.features()) {
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature feature = iter.next();
                    IDs.add(feature.getIdentifier());

                    System.out.println("   " + feature.getIdentifier());
                }
            }

            if (IDs.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("   no feature selected");
            }

            displaySelectedFeatures(IDs);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void refreshMap() {
        ReferencedEnvelope env = new ReferencedEnvelope(map.getViewport().getBounds());
        doSetDisplayArea(env);
    }

    private void initPaintThread() {
        ScheduledService<Boolean> svc = new ScheduledService<Boolean>() {
            protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
                return new Task<Boolean>() {
                    protected Boolean call() {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> drawMap(gc));
                        return true;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        svc.setPeriod(Duration.millis(1000.0 / PAINT_HZ));
        svc.start();
    }

    private void doSetDisplayArea(ReferencedEnvelope envelope) {
        map.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);
        repaint = true;
    }

    public void saveImage(MapContent map, File file, int imageWidth) {
        GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
        renderer.setMapContent(map);

        Rectangle imageBounds;
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds;
        try {
            mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
            double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
            imageBounds = new Rectangle(
                    0, 0, imageWidth, (int) Math.round(imageWidth * heightToWidth));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // failed to access map layers
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageBounds.width, imageBounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
        gr.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        gr.fill(imageBounds);

        try {
            renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<Distribution> getDistributionsInsert() {
        return list(writer, polygonListInsert);
    }

    public ObservableList<Distribution> getDistributionsUpdate() {
        return list(writer, polygonListUpdate);
    }

    public ObservableList<Distribution> getDistributionsDelete() {
        return list(writer, polygonListDelete);
    }

    private ObservableList<Distribution> list(WKTWriter writer, ObservableList<Geometry> polygonList) {
        return polygonList.stream()
                .map(geometry -> {
                    Distribution distribution = new Distribution();
                    distribution.setSpecies(species.getId());
                    distribution.setGeometry(writer.write(geometry));
                    return distribution;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
    }


    // docs end select features

    // docs start display selected

    /**
     * Sets the display to paint selected features yellow and unselected features in the default
     * style.
     *
     * @param IDs identifiers of currently selected features
     */
    public void displaySelectedFeatures(Set<FeatureId> IDs) {
        Style style;

        if (IDs.isEmpty()) {
            style = createDefaultStyle();

        } else {
            style = createSelectedStyle(IDs);
        }

        //here i put selected layer
        selectedLayer.set(map.layers().get(0));
        ((FeatureLayer) selectedLayer.get()).setStyle(style);
        refreshMap();
    }
    // docs end display selected

    // docs start default style

    /**
     * Create a default Style for feature display
     */
    private Style createDefaultStyle() {
        Rule rule = createRule(LINE_COLOUR, FILL_COLOUR);

        FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle();
        fts.rules().add(rule);

        Style style = sf.createStyle();
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
        return style;
    }
    // docs end default style

    // docs start selected style

    /**
     * Create a Style where features with given IDs are painted yellow, while others are painted
     * with the default colors.
     */
    private Style createSelectedStyle(Set<FeatureId> IDs) {
        Rule selectedRule = createRule(SELECTED_COLOUR, SELECTED_COLOUR);
        selectedRule.setFilter(ff.id(IDs));

        Rule otherRule = createRule(LINE_COLOUR, FILL_COLOUR);
        otherRule.setElseFilter(true);

        FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle();
        fts.rules().add(selectedRule);
        fts.rules().add(otherRule);

        Style style = sf.createStyle();
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
        return style;
    }
    // docs end selected style

    // docs start create rule

    /**
     * Helper for createXXXStyle methods. Creates a new Rule containing a Symbolizer tailored to the
     * geometry type of the features that we are displaying.
     */
    private Rule createRule(Color outlineColor, Color fillColor) {
        Symbolizer symbolizer = null;
        Fill fill;
        Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(outlineColor), ff.literal(LINE_WIDTH));

        switch (geometryType) {
            case POLYGON:
                fill = sf.createFill(ff.literal(fillColor), ff.literal(OPACITY));
                symbolizer = sf.createPolygonSymbolizer(stroke, fill, geometryAttributeName);
                break;

            case LINE:
                symbolizer = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, geometryAttributeName);
                break;

            case POINT:
                fill = sf.createFill(ff.literal(fillColor), ff.literal(OPACITY));

                Mark mark = sf.getCircleMark();
                mark.setFill(fill);
                mark.setStroke(stroke);

                Graphic graphic = sf.createDefaultGraphic();
                graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
                graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(mark);
                graphic.setSize(ff.literal(POINT_SIZE));

                symbolizer = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, geometryAttributeName);
        }

        Rule rule = sf.createRule();
        rule.symbolizers().add(symbolizer);
        return rule;
    }

    private MapContent loadMap() throws IOException {
        if (map == null || map.layers().isEmpty()) {
            map = new MapContent();
            URL source = Main.class.getResource("resource/map/CUB_adm0.shp");
            FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(source);
            featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

            setGeometry();

            Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
            Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
            map.addLayer(layer);
        }
        return map;
    }

    private void setGeometry() {
        GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = featureSource.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
        geometryAttributeName = geomDesc.getLocalName();

        Class<?> clazz = geomDesc.getType().getBinding();

        if (Polygon.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) || MultiPolygon.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            geometryType = GeomType.POLYGON;

        } else if (LineString.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
                || MultiLineString.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {

            geometryType = GeomType.LINE;

        } else {
            geometryType = GeomType.POINT;
        }
    }

}
```

And the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="cu.edu.cujae.guatini.controller.speciesTabController.DistribTabPageController">
    <Canvas fx:id="mapCanvas" height="300.0" width="700.0"/>
</Pane>
```

I'm using `geotools 19.2` and to show mapCanvas in fxml needs [ejml](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download) dependencies. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing is exactly what you asked the program to do. In `selectLayer` you search for features in `featureSource` that intersect a box surrounding your click. `featureSource` contains the features from `CUB_adm0.shp` (loaded in `loadMap`).

If you want to select (and delete) a feature from the polygon layer you need to search in that layer for the intersecting polygons. Looking at `addGeometry` it seems that you create a new layer for each polygon but don't keep track of them. I would use a single global layer to store the polygons and then use that in `selectLayer` to find the polygon to delete.